# Bash : how to pass arguments to a heredoc script

Tags: bash, shell-script, here-document

Imagine you have a silly script test.sh to which arguments are passed that would look like this:

```bsh
bash test.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

with test.sh being a silly script that displays its command line:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$0 $*"
```

I would like to do the same using bash heredoc << to feed the script to bash.
So I tried this :

```bsh
bash <<'EOF' -- arg1 arg2 arg3
echo "$0 $*"
EOF
```

But it fails with error

```
bash: arg1: No such file or directory
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The here document is passed to the inner bash on its standard input. You need to instruct bash to read from standard input. With no command line arguments, this happens automatically. If there's at least one non-option argument and no `-s` or `-c` option, the first non-option argument is the name of the script file to run. You can pass the `-s` option to tell bash to read from standard input.

```
bash <<'EOF' -s -- arg1 arg2 arg3
echo "$0 $*"
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, on most systems, you can do:

```
bash /dev/fd/3 3<< 'EOF' arg1 arg2 arg3
echo "$0 $*"
IFS= read -rp "Enter something: "
printf 'You entered: "%s"\n' "$REPLY"
EOF
```

That way, your here-script can still access stdin.